# SQLAlchemy Query Not Behaving As Should

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am trying to execute a query within Python using SQLAlchemy. Everything is working and I can connect to the DB, retrieve from it and write to it. But this executes a piece of code that does not seem to work.

```
engine.execute("WITH CTE_DATA AS (   SELECT [RowNum] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Level DESC)  FROM Thursday_crypto )  DELETE  FROM CTE_DATA  WHERE RowNum > 1") # Not working


engine.execute("CREATE TABLE Persons (    PersonID int,    LastName varchar(255),    FirstName varchar(255),    Address varchar(255),    City varchar(255));") # Working
```

Query 1 doesn't work, but it works when I run it within SQLServer as a query.

Query 2 works here, so I know it is connecting and executing with no problems in general, just seems to be query 1 that doesn't execute.

I have tried adding

```
engine.connect()
```

and

```
engine.execute("COMMIT;")
```

Before and after the query as some posts have started to do, but still did not work.

The issue is, nothing is happening. The python code runs fine with no errors occurring and nothing happens to the SQL table. Meaning it seems as though the query is not executing.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Following on from my comments, this is the code I tried whereby it said commit was not as object:

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
          conn.execute("WITH CTE_DATA AS (   SELECT [RowNum] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Level DESC)  FROM Thursday_crypto )  DELETE  FROM CTE_DATA  WHERE RowNum > 1")
          conn.commit()
```

EDIT:

```
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute("WITH CTE_DATA AS (   SELECT [RowNum] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Level DESC)  FROM Thursday_crypto )  DELETE  FROM CTE_DATA  WHERE RowNum > 1")
```

The above works and executes to SQLServer, I am not sure why the other ways did not but I guess it is to do with 'WITH'

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you get an error? Unexpected results? Undesired behaviour? Your PC suffers a catastrophic failure? Something else?

Comment: @Larnu - nothing happens... the python code runs with no errors and nothing happens to the SQL table. Undesired behavior

Comment: [Edit] your question to explain that, ro_quant.

Comment: Are you using one of the SqlAlchemy 1.x versions? Its autocommit behavior is not exactly foolproof since it doesn't catch statements that don't start with the `delete`, `insert`, `update`, etc. keywords. Have you tried using `engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=True)` or manually creating and committing a transaction around the statement?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I am using 1.4.28. I see, I will give this a try ```engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=True)```

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Sadly, did not work. This is what I tried: ```engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=True)
                                                                                                                 engine.execute("WITH CTE_DATA AS (   SELECT [RowNum] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Level DESC)  FROM Thursday_crypto )  DELETE  FROM CTE_DATA  WHERE RowNum > 1")``` Am I doing it correctly or am I missing something? Should I add a BEGIN / COMMIT somewhere?

Comment: Have a read through the [Transactions and Connection Management](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html) documentation for example usages.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning This seemed the only logical solution  ```with engine.connect() as conn:
            conn.execute("WITH CTE_DATA AS (   SELECT [RowNum] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Level DESC)  FROM Thursday_crypto )  DELETE  FROM CTE_DATA  WHERE RowNum > 1")
            conn.commit() ```  But its saying commit isnt an object of connection

Comment: That `conn` should certainly have a `commit` method; is the call to `commit` correctly indented?  It would be much easier to tell if you [edit] the question to include code updates, they're hard to read in the comments.  Note you could also use `with engine.begin() as conn:`, which will `commit` automatically.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I have edited it to show what I tried when it returned the commit issue. The commit and the execute are indented the same. I will try ```engine.begin()```

Comment: @snakecharmerb ```engine.begin()``` works! I don't know why the other ways do not, but this seems to. I have added the full snippet to the question if you want to add it as an answer